# Should I use grouping specific elements in XML schema?

Tags: xml, schema, grouping, nested

I'm trying to build an XML-based data definition for an inter-departmental database.  I cannot discern the advantages/disadvantages, or whether best practices exist, for using grouping elements in the schema.  It adds an extra layer of nesting, but also seems to help break things out visually.  For example:

```
<Experiment>
  .
  .
  .
  <Samples>
    <Sample>
      <Name>First Sample</Name>
      <Reviewed/>
      <Total/>
      <OrderNumber/>
    </Sample>
    <Sample>
      <Name>Second Sample</Name>
      <Reviewed/>
      <Total/>
      <OrderNumber/>
    </Sample>
  </Samples>
</Experiment>
```

versus (without grouping):

```
<Experiment>
  .
  .
  .
  <Sample>
    <Name>First Sample</Name>
    <Reviewed/>
    <Total/>
    <OrderNumber/>
  </Sample>
  <Sample>
    <Name>Second Sample</Name>
    <Reviewed/>
    <Total/>
    <OrderNumber/>
  </Sample>
</Experiment>
```

Any preferences or best practices?

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to give general advice on this one. The extra wrapper layer will sometimes make processing a bit easier - or at any rate, some kinds of processing; but if you overdo it, the XML can become so deeply nested as to become unmanageable. As with all such decisions, sometimes the extreme positions (always add wrappers, never add wrappers) give the worst outcomes. Some cases where wrappers can be most useful: (a) if there are attributes associated with the group, (b) if there is more than one group with the same parent element.